# How to force the character encoding of HTML e-mails in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, actionmailer

I'm using Rails 3.1 (3.1.1 RC1) and I have configured ActionMailer to use `windows-1252` as default encoding. (External requirement)

This works perfectly with plain text mails, but as soon as I send HTML mails the text is converted to `UTF-8` again resulting in garbled text.

Here's what I've done/found out.

- I configured the default encoding: `ActionMailer::Base.default :charset => 'windows-1252'`
- My .erb template is actually `windows-1252` encoded.
- I added the required marker `<%# encoding: windows-1252 -%>` as the first line of the template.
- The mail has a correct content type header: `Content-Type: text/html; charset="windows-1252"`

Here's the code snippet I'm using to send the mail:

```
mail(:to => ..., :subject => "...") do |format|
  format.html
end
```

I suspect that somehow during mail processing Rails/ActionMailer decides to convert the characters to UTF-8. How can I change that?

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention what version of Ruby you are using (1.9.x do things differently then 1.8.x,) but assuming you are using a 1.9 version, you can set the following in your application.rb:

```
config.encoding = "windows-1252"
```

Which will set an application wide encoding. (which is utf-8 by default)

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use the charset option within the mailer.

See here: http://railsdispatch.com/posts/actionmailer

Comment: I thought doing this in the mailer itself could change something