# ActionMailer HTML Encoding Hell - Special Chars Replaced With Garbage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8, actionmailer

I have UTF-8 string: `Website • Facebook`
That is a bullet in the middle aka `&bull;` or `0xE2 0x80 0xA2`

This value is correctly stored in the database and correctly displayed on screen using Rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3 using the default settings.

I am attempting to send this via HTML email, but when all is said and done, the receiving end sees garbage:

[image]

The code behind this is simple, I have an `ActionMailer` subclass (which uses UTF-8 by default) setup to send an HTML email with UTF-8 content encoding in the layout:

`email.html.erb` layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=9" />       
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>       
</head>
<body class='email'>
    <%= yield %>                        
</body>
</html>
```

The content uses the same views that render the webpage, with the important line being:

```
<p><%= simple_format strip_tags(comment.text) %></p>
```

I have tried many many permutations of `force_encoding`, `encode`, applying redundant UTF-8 encoding to the `ActionMailer` subclass, the top of the view file and about a dozen other things, but nothing seems to work.

The important HTML, as viewed by [the raw html message](https://gist.github.com/4331131) through Apple Mail is:

```
Website =EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD Facebook
```

If you take a look at the raw message (linked above), this does not occur on the text-only message, only the HTML one.

**TL;DR**

ActionMailer is replacing what should be a UTF-8 bullet character:`0xE2 0x80 0xA2`
with garbage: `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you are having the same problem as I: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556173/how-to-force-the-character-encoding-of-html-e-mails-in-rails-3

Comment: Maybe... but the encoding of the HTML in the raw message is correctly set as UTF-8 for me. That bullet char is UTF-8

Comment: Some things to consider: [Some mail senders may corrupt your emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543694/rails-actionmailer-encoding). If you are using [a gem for inlining CSS](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbrunsfeld/blog/articles/2344-no-go-on-nogo) it may screw up the HTML.

Comment: I think there is some truth to this. I disabled my premailer-rails3 gem and the bullet shows as intended. Please convert your comment into an answer so I can reward you with a fat 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are using a gem for inlining CSS, like `premailer-rails3`.

[According to this post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbrunsfeld/blog/articles/2344-no-go-on-nogo), this may corrupt UTF-8 characters in your ActionMailer emails.

Try either removing or replacing the gem with something like the `actionmailer_inline_css` gem.